# Dynamically creating sitemap for my website on linux server

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

I run a website. I add content to the website severally in a day.

I want to generate a site map that will dynamically change with change in content.

Have done some searches but only saw manual sitemap builders.

My website does not run on wordpress, joomla or any other cms (it was custom built)

How do i go about generating the sitemap

Thanks!

Comment: Do pages get added to your site "dynamically"?  Whatever publishing process you currently use, add an additional step and update your sitemap.

Comment: @AJ yes pages get added...  your suggestion is not clear, pls explain

Comment: You don't provide exact details of your site, so it is difficult to know is a suggested answer is going to suit your case.

Comment: @crafter its a job site, new jobs get added daily, i want the new jobs to appear on the sitemap, thanks

Comment: A sitemap is not intended to be an index of every piece of dynamic data in your application.

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to build a custom sitemap.xml generator, in PHP pulling in data from your database.
Alternatively you can use an external crawler (Looks at your site the way any user would) which would crawl through every page on your site reading and saving links. This is more CPU intensive and takes longer. Check out http://enarion.net/tools/phpsitemapng/ as an example (Works in PHP too)